# Generated SQL script from workbench doesn`t work on MariaDB server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I created a scheme in mysql workbench and exported this scheme into SQL code.
.

When I want to generate table user on my server I am getting error.

Script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'user' (
  'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'registerDate' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  'login' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  'password' VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  'status' TINYINT NOT NULL,
  'credits' INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
  UNIQUE INDEX 'login_UNIQUE' ('login' ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

> Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''user' ( 'id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'registerDate' TIMESTAMP NOT NU' at line 1

I don`t understand where is an error? I didn`t see anything wrong.

Version on server: `10.1.32-MariaDB`

Comment: Remove Single quotes from table and column names

Comment: @Hi, now I am getting an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 9

Comment: Remove the keyword `VISIBLE` -- Workbench knows it, but MariaDB does not.

Comment: Thank you, finally working! Is there any way how to "export sql script in mariadb form" from mysqlworkbench